# Let $K⊆M⊆L$, such that $[L:K]=n$ for some $n∈\mathbb{N}$. Prove $[M:K]$ is well-defined.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I wanted to delve into Galois theory as soon as possible, so I started reading a book on the topic without previous knowledge of other areas of mathematics which are often needed to understand Galois. Because of this I do not understand the usual definition of a field extension (which makes use of the concept of a Vector Space), but rather employ a different (I believe equivalent) definition:

Let $L, K$ be subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $K⊆L$

Let $A = $ {$x_1, ..., x_n$} $⊆L$ be a set of linearly independent elements over $K$ such that $L = $ {$x_1k_1+...+x_nk_n|k_i∈K$}, then $[L:K]=n$. We call $A$ a basis for $L:K$.

From such definition, is it possible to prove that if $K⊆M⊆L$, such that $[L:K]=n$ for some $n∈\mathbb{N}$ then $[M:K]$ is well defined. In other words, that there exists a set $B⊆M$  which is a basis for $M:K$.

I'm aware my definition only speaks of finite field extensions.

I would really appreciate any help/thoughts.

Comment: The *dimension* of a vector space is well defined, and it is the cardinality of any of its basis.

Comment: All subfields of $\Bbb{C}$ contain $\Bbb{Q}$, so they have infinitely many elements. Therefore [tag:finite-fields] was an inappropriate tag.

Comment: Anyway, you may benefit from reviewing a bit of linear algebra. $L$ is a finitely generated vector space over $K$, and $M$ is a subspace. Therefore $M$ is also finitely generated.

Comment: @Berci. I'm aware that by using the concept of a Vector Space my question can be easily answered. Yet I was wondering if there was a way to prove the statement without making use of such concept.

Comment: Well, looking for (the existence of) a 'basis' is typically a linear algebra task, you might use different terminology, seemingly avoiding vector spaces, but in the end, it's just the theorem you're going to use that any basis of a subspace extends to the ambient vector space.

Comment: Could someone direct me to a proof that the dimension of a Vector Space is always well-defined?